# char double pointer confusing behaviour

Tags: c, pointers

I'm doing an exercise at https://www.codingame.com/ to practice some C pointers.

The task is to translate input characters into ASCII art.
For example the letter A is:

```
 # 
# #
###
# #
# #
```

https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/ascii-art

The whole ASCII alphabet is provided as a single input of different rows (A to Z plus ?):

```
 #  ##   ## ##  ### ###  ## # # ###  ## # # #   # # ###  #  ##   #  ##   ## ### # # # # # # # # # # ### ### 
# # # # #   # # #   #   #   # #  #    # # # #   ### # # # # # # # # # # #    #  # # # # # # # # # #   #   # 
### ##  #   # # ##  ##  # # ###  #    # ##  #   ### # # # # ##  # # ##   #   #  # # # # ###  #   #   #   ## 
# # # # #   # # #   #   # # # #  #  # # # # #   # # # # # # #    ## # #   #  #  # # # # ### # #  #  #       
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #
```

I'm trying to store the alphabet as a double pointer (alphabet_input).

```
char ** alphabet_input;

int main()
{
    int length = 4;
    int height = 5;

    alphabet_input = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*height);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        char ROW[1025];
        fgets(ROW, 1025, stdin);

        alphabet_input[i] = ROW;

        // print alphabet lines for the first time
        printf("%s", alphabet_input[i]);
    }

    // print alphabet lines for the second time
    printf("%s", alphabet_input[0]);
    printf("%s", alphabet_input[1]);
    printf("%s", alphabet_input[2]);
    printf("%s", alphabet_input[3]);
    printf("%s", alphabet_input[4]);

    return 0;
}
```

However when I try to print it I'm getting the last line repeatedly. This is what I'm getting as results:

```
 #  ##   ## ##  ### ###  ## # # ###  ## # # #   # # ###  #  ##   #  ##   ## ### # # # # # # # # # # ### ### 
# # # # #   # # #   #   #   # #  #    # # # #   ### # # # # # # # # # # #    #  # # # # # # # # # #   #   # 
### ##  #   # # ##  ##  # # ###  #    # ##  #   ### # # # # ##  # # ##   #   #  # # # # ###  #   #   #   ## 
# # # # #   # # #   #   # # # #  #  # # # # #   # # # # # # #    ## # #   #  #  # # # # ### # #  #  #       
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #  
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #  
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #  
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #  
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #  
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #
```

I expected to get the input printed twice:

```
 #  ##   ## ##  ### ###  ## # # ###  ## # # #   # # ###  #  ##   #  ##   ## ### # # # # # # # # # # ### ### 
# # # # #   # # #   #   #   # #  #    # # # #   ### # # # # # # # # # # #    #  # # # # # # # # # #   #   # 
### ##  #   # # ##  ##  # # ###  #    # ##  #   ### # # # # ##  # # ##   #   #  # # # # ###  #   #   #   ## 
# # # # #   # # #   #   # # # #  #  # # # # #   # # # # # # #    ## # #   #  #  # # # # ### # #  #  #       
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #  
 #  ##   ## ##  ### ###  ## # # ###  ## # # #   # # ###  #  ##   #  ##   ## ### # # # # # # # # # # ### ### 
# # # # #   # # #   #   #   # #  #    # # # #   ### # # # # # # # # # # #    #  # # # # # # # # # #   #   # 
### ##  #   # # ##  ##  # # ###  #    # ##  #   ### # # # # ##  # # ##   #   #  # # # # ###  #   #   #   ## 
# # # # #   # # #   #   # # # #  #  # # # # #   # # # # # # #    ## # #   #  #  # # # # ### # #  #  #       
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #
```

How should I manipulate the indexes of alphabet_input to properly print each row as a string?

I'm really confused because printing inside the for loop seems to work just fine. However right after it the indexing seems to break down.

Comment: "H represents number of vertical chars" then... maybe you should call it `num_vertical` or something. Give variables good names. `H` , `L` , `T` certainly aren't.

Comment: the variable names come from the problem definition... I agree maybe I could change the code to improve readability here

Comment: The problem definition doesn't dictate what names you use internally in your code. Just what the output has to be for specific input.

Comment: I made a few modifications to try to make it easier to understand.

Comment: thank you, my comment was just some friendly advice.

Comment: how is `length` used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
    char ROW[1025];
    fgets(ROW, 1025, stdin);
    alphabet_input[i] = ROW;
}
```

The variable `ROW` is in the scope of the for body, therefore it is created and destroyed at each for iteration. You point `alphabet_input[i]` at this variable which is immediately destroyed at the end of iteration so you end up with dangling pointers.

Instead of pointing `alphabet[i]` to a local variable, you need to allocate space for it and then copy the contents of the line into it.

```
char ** alphabet_input;
alphabet_input = malloc(height * sizeof *alphabet_input);

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    char row[1025];
    fgets(row, 1025, stdin);

    size_t len = strlen(row);

    alphabet_input[i] = malloc(len + 1);
    strcpy(alphabet_input[i], row);
}
```

You might want to tune the above code depending on how you want the length be (e.g. 1025 instead of strlen, or remove the trailing new line etc.)

A few points I would like to make:

- this is how I would recommend writing the `malloc`:

  ```
  pointer_var = <no cast> malloc(<num_elements> * sizeof *pointer_var);
  alphabet_input = malloc(height * sizeof *alphabet_input);
  ```
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` by the standard so you can skip `sizeof(char)` in `malloc`:

  ```
  alphabet_input[i] = malloc(len + 1);
  ```
- avoid all uppercase variable. They are generally used for macros in C.

Comment: @BernardoRodrigues you are welcome. It is important to understand what is happening, more than to see it is working.